# Can I migrate a Flutter app to a native iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, mobile, mobile-development

Myself and a team are starting a potential startup and one of the things we want to do is a mobile app. We have already identified the target audience to mainly be iPhone users. But here in the US there's still plenty of Android user so we've been considering using a cross platform framework like Flutter. I've seen a lot of praise that Flutter is easy to use and can help us deliver an MVP faster. My ideal situation is to start developing with Flutter and when the app is successful migrate it to a native iOS app using Swift. But is that possible at all? Or if we decide to go native when we already have a flutter app, do we need to start from scratch?

Comment: I also wanted to point out that the two developers on the team are new to mobile but experienced in web dev.

Answer (score 3):

Developing a Flutter app is completely different from developing an Android or iOS app. It has different language, has it's own architechture with it's own packages/dependencies/plugins.

You cannot convert from one of them to the other.